# Why does my confusion matrix look like this?

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

This is my predictive modeling code for fraud detection on the AML dataset

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.utils.data as Data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, precision_score, f1_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE


class MyDataset(Data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

        X = df.values[:, :-1]
        y = df.values[:, -1]
        smote = SMOTE()
        X_resampled, y_resampled = smote.fit_resample(X, y)

        self.X = torch.tensor(X_resampled, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.y = torch.tensor(y_resampled, dtype=torch.long)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.X[index], self.y[index]


class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out


def calculate_metrics(predictions, targets):
    accuracy = accuracy_score(targets, predictions)
    recall = recall_score(targets, predictions)
    precision = precision_score(targets, predictions)
    f1 = f1_score(targets, predictions)
    cm = confusion_matrix(targets, predictions)
    return accuracy, recall, precision, f1, cm


# Define the training function  
def train(train_loader, val_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        model.train()
        for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            val_predictions = []
            val_targets = []
            for inputs, labels in val_loader:
                outputs = model(inputs)
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                val_predictions.extend(predicted.tolist())
                val_targets.extend(labels.tolist())

            val_predictions = np.array(val_predictions)
            val_targets = np.array(val_targets)

            accuracy, recall, precision, f1, cm = calculate_metrics(val_predictions, val_targets)

            print('Epoch [{}/{}], Validation Accuracy: {:.2f}%, Recall: {:.2f}, Precision: {:.2f}, F1 Score: {:.2f}'
                  .format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, accuracy * 100, recall, precision, f1))
            print('Confusion Matrix:\n', cm)


file_path = 'D:/Program Files/JetBrains/Finance/AML/transactions_processed.csv'
dataset = MyDataset(file_path)

train_dataset = []
val_dataset = []
test_dataset = []

for i in range(len(dataset)):
    x, y = dataset[i]
    timestamp = x[-2]

    threshold_train = 119
    threshold_val = 159
    if timestamp < threshold_train:
        train_dataset.append((x, y))
    elif threshold_train <= timestamp < threshold_val:
        val_dataset.append((x, y))
    else:
        test_dataset.append((x, y))

train_dataset = Data.TensorDataset(torch.stack([sample[0] for sample in train_dataset]), torch.tensor([sample[1] for sample in train_dataset]))
val_dataset = Data.TensorDataset(torch.stack([sample[0] for sample in val_dataset]), torch.tensor([sample[1] for sample in val_dataset]))
test_dataset = Data.TensorDataset(torch.stack([sample[0] for sample in test_dataset]), torch.tensor([sample[1] for sample in test_dataset]))

train_loader = Data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
val_loader = Data.DataLoader(dataset=val_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)
test_loader = Data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)

model = MLP(input_size=7, hidden_size=64, num_classes=2)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

train(train_loader, val_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=10)

model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    test_predictions = []
    test_targets = []
    for inputs, labels in test_loader:
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        test_predictions.extend(predicted.tolist())
        test_targets.extend(labels.tolist())

    test_predictions = np.array(test_predictions)
    test_targets = np.array(test_targets)

    # Calculate metrics for the test set  
    accuracy, recall, precision, f1, cm = calculate_metrics(test_predictions, test_targets)
    print('Test Accuracy: {:.2f}%, Recall: {:.2f}, Precision: {:.2f}, F1 Score: {:.2f}'
          .format(accuracy * 100, recall, precision, f1))
    print('Confusion Matrix:\n', cm)
```

Here's my output:

Epoch [1/10], Validation Accuracy: 97.14%, Recall: 0.94, Precision: 1.00, F1 Score: 0.97
Confusion Matrix:
[[266144      0]
[ 14861 238894]]

Epoch [2/10], Validation Accuracy: 83.31%, Recall: 1.00, Precision: 0.75, F1 Score: 0.85
Confusion Matrix:
[[179397  86747]
[     0 253755]]

Epoch [3/10], Validation Accuracy: 90.43%, Recall: 0.80, Precision: 1.00, F1 Score: 0.89
Confusion Matrix:
[[266144      0]
[ 49763 203992]]

Epoch [4/10], Validation Accuracy: 99.66%, Recall: 1.00, Precision: 0.99, F1 Score: 1.00
Confusion Matrix:
[[264383   1761]
[     0 253755]]

Epoch [5/10], Validation Accuracy: 93.68%, Recall: 1.00, Precision: 0.89, F1 Score: 0.94
Confusion Matrix:
[[233307  32837]
[     0 253755]]

Epoch [6/10], Validation Accuracy: 98.91%, Recall: 0.98, Precision: 1.00, F1 Score: 0.99
Confusion Matrix:
[[266144      0]
[  5681 248074]]

Epoch [7/10], Validation Accuracy: 99.16%, Recall: 0.98, Precision: 1.00, F1 Score: 0.99
Confusion Matrix:
[[266144      0]
[  4360 249395]]

Epoch [8/10], Validation Accuracy: 99.78%, Recall: 1.00, Precision: 1.00, F1 Score: 1.00
Confusion Matrix:
[[266144      0]
[  1121 252634]]

Epoch [9/10], Validation Accuracy: 99.97%, Recall: 1.00, Precision: 1.00, F1 Score: 1.00
Confusion Matrix:
[[266144      0]
[   147 253608]]

Epoch [10/10], Validation Accuracy: 100.00%, Recall: 1.00, Precision: 1.00, F1 Score: 1.00
Confusion Matrix:
[[266144      0]
[     0 253755]]

Test Accuracy: 99.97%, Recall: 1.00, Precision: 1.00, F1 Score: 1.00
Confusion Matrix:
[[272648      0]
[   155 295508]]

I'm trying to figure out why FP and FT are rotating to 0?

Comment: 1) I'm not sure I understand: wouldn't you want your confusion matrix to have most entries along the diagonal of the matrix? This seems like perfectly fine performance. 2) I understand what FP is - can you clarify what FT is?